Styles not applying correctly when printing in Vue.js/Vuetify app in production
I'm experiencing an issue with my Vue.js/Vuetify application where the print styles are not being applied correctly in the production environment, but they work fine in localhost. Both Firefox and Chrome show the same behavior.
localhost

production

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can you provide insights on what might be going wrong?
Thank you!
Here's a brief overview of what I've tried:

Checked that all resources are loading without any errors in the console.
Ensured that the media queries for print were defined correctly in my CSS.
Tried clearing the browser cache and disabling all minification during build.


You should provide a minimal reproduction for others to help you.
